# Performant distro for development & personal use

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, development

#### Background

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04**.

**Laptop specs:**

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00 GHz × 4
- Graphics Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
- 8 GB of RAM
- OS type: 64-bit
- Windowing System: X11
- System drive: HDD

#### Issue

My system takes so much time to boot and lags a lot when running watchers on vscode.

Is there a Linux distro designed specifically for *web development* and *personal use*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Long answer: Given your specs you shouldn't expect a completely smooth experience on any OS (be it windows or any Linux distro) for modern applications. However you can optimize, if you're already familiar with Ubuntu/Debian than try the minimal version of Ubuntu and install only the things you need, if that's not enough then there's Lubuntu which is very lightweight.

Another (possibly irrelevant) option is to replace the HDD with an SSD, it's probably the main bottleneck.

Comment: Suggest SSD. I upgraded my Kubuntu Skylake i5-6500 to NVMe from SSD. Not huge improvement over SSD, but 7.8 sec boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster My older Haswell i5-4690K with SSD says 24.498s and 
graphical.target reached after 3.177s in userspace. Have not recently reviewed settings  on Haswell. Did notice changing from Ubuntu to Kubuntu also improved things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer